# consC in Seasoned Schemer

Tags: scheme, let, seasoned-schemer

The seasoned schemer on page 131 and 132 has the below definition of consC and deep.

```
(define consC 
  (let ((N 0)) 
   (lambda (x y) 
    (set! N (add1 N)) 
    (cons z y))))

(define deep
  (lambda (m)
    (if (zero? m)
      (quote pizza)
      (consC (deep (sub1 m))
        (quote ())))))
```

I have a problem that when deep use consC each time to recursion,why (let ((N 0)) don't reset N to 0?

Comment: Why should it? The `let` initialization only happens once, when `condC` is defined. The term you'll want to research is "closure"

Comment: Is `z` supposed to be `x` in that?

Comment: If you keep reading you'll see versions that let you see the counter and set it to arbitrary values like 0, btw.

Comment: Hi Shawn，my thought of ’let‘ may reset value  in recursion is from page 124-125 in this book.In here, author use 'biz' function to  Y-bang and Y, Y have eventual value but Y-bang not. I think the reason maybe 'biz' have (let ((x 0))  on the top,which Y-bang reset this value to 0 but Y not contain this (let ((x 0)) to recursion. So if  this is true, ’let‘ may reset value  in recursion.As you say, 'let initialization only happens once',so what reason for 'biz' to Y and Y-bang? @Shawn

Comment: In that the second call to `biz` never stops recursing because its counter is never reset; which y combinator implementation is being used doesn't matter.